# Control Parameter for Coulomb Phase of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, yang-mills, superconformality

When discussing the vacua of $\mathcal{N}=4$ super-Yang-Mills (SYM) theory (with any connected gauge group you like, such as $U(N)$ or $SU(N)$), a simple analysis of the potential tells you the vacuum state must have
$$\langle[\phi_i,\phi_j]\rangle=0,$$
where $\phi_i$ are the (adjoint-valued) scalar fields of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM and $i,j$ run from 1 to 6. Of course there are two ways to achieve this, and consequently two phases:

1. $\langle\phi_i\rangle=0$ for all scalars. This doesn't break any symmetries and hence is the superconformal phase.
2. $\langle\phi_i\rangle\ne0$, which means that the $\phi_i$'s take on values in the Cartan algebra, hence breaking the symmetry to $U(1)^r$, where $r$ is the rank of the gauge group. This is the Coulomb phase, with the name coming from the presence of $U(1)$ factors.

Obviously, the order parameter for the transition between superconformal and Coulomb phases is the VEVs of the scalar fields; however, what is the control parameter of this transition?

Comment: What is the control parameter?

Comment: That's my question.

Comment: Could you give example of such object?

Comment: Oh sorry you mean define control parameter? It's like the thing you change to cause a phase transition. For example, for the liquid-solid transition in water, the control parameter is just the temperature.

Comment: It is order parametr. In YM theory order parametr is Wilson loop. I think in SYM one can also consider gauge invariant $tr(\phi^i \phi^i)$.

Comment: I'm asking about the control parameter, not the order parameter.

Comment: What is difference between control and order parameters?

Comment: Control parameters are what changes to cause a transition, and order parameters are what property signals a transition. For example, in a ferromagnet-paramagnet transition, the control parameter is temperature and the order parameter is net magnetization.